# How to add log statement to Android RecyclerView class?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am running into an IllegalArgumentException in the RecyclerView class. I would like to add a log statement to recycleViewHolderInternal(ViewHolder holder) method, so I can find out which ViewHolder, or item, is causing the exception. How would I be able to add a log statement to the method?

I have thought about creating a subclass of the RecyclerView and overriding the recycleViewHolder method, but that would force me to replace all of my RecyclerView instances with the one I created. I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: you mean the Adapter which extends RecyclerView Adapter?

Comment: Why not use breakpoints and the debugger?

Comment: I would normally breakpoint the crash, but it happens so infrequently that I just want to log it remotely when it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a [custom uncaught exception handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) and put your logging code in it. Or, even better, use a dedicated crash reporting service like [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics).